# Looping date and time in selected date period

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop

Halo, i have a problem to loop date and time in PHP. I have initial value for start date, end date , start time and end time.
I want to loop `20131201` until `20131210` with time from `0540` until `0600`.

I run my code, but it just loop in `20131201`.

```
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0540', '0545', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0545', '0550', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0550', '0555', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0555', '0600', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
```

I want it loop and have result like this :

```
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0540', '0545', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0545', '0550', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0550', '0555', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131201', '20131210', '0555', '0600', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')

INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131202', '20131210', '0540', '0545', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131202', '20131210', '0545', '0550', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131202', '20131210', '0550', '0555', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131202', '20131210', '0555', '0600', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')

INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131203', '20131210', '0540', '0545', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131203', '20131210', '0545', '0550', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131203', '20131210', '0550', '0555', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
INSERT INTO golf_list VALUES ('', 'others', '', '20131203', '20131210', '0555', '0600', 'IDR', '4','', 'royal', '0')
```

... and so on ... until 10 steps...

**This is my code :**

```
$start_date = "20131201";
    $end_date = "20131210";

    $start_hour = "05";
    $start_min = "40";

    $end_hour = "06";
    $end_min = "00";
    //$end_time = $end_hour."".$end_minute;

    //$players = $_POST['players'];
    /*
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $price_standard = $_POST['price_standard'];
    $price_extra = $_POST['price_extra'];
    */
    $price_type = 4;
$details = "";

    $start = new DateTime("$start_hour$start_min");
    $end = new DateTime("$end_hour$end_min");

    for($i = $start_date; $i <= $end_date; $i++) {
        while($start < $end) {
            $start_time = $start->format('Hi');
            $start->modify('+5 minute');
            $end_time = $start->format('Hi');

            $query1 = "INSERT INTO golf_list (golf_name, golf_type,  location, start_date, end_date, start_time, 
                        end_time, currency, price_type, details, gate, status)
                        VALUES ('', 'others', '', '$i', '$end_date', '$start_time', 
                                '$end_time', 'IDR', '$price_type','$details', 'royal', '0')";

            echo "$query1<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Any solutions? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$start_date = "20131201";
    $end_date = "20131210";

    $start_hour = "05";
    $start_min = "40";

    $end_hour = "06";
    $end_min = "00";
    //$end_time = $end_hour."".$end_minute;

    //$players = $_POST['players'];
    /*
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $price_standard = $_POST['price_standard'];
    $price_extra = $_POST['price_extra'];
    */
    $price_type = 4;
    $details = "";



    for($i = $start_date; $i <= $end_date; $i++) {

    $start = new DateTime("$start_hour$start_min");
    $end = new DateTime("$end_hour$end_min");


        for($j = $start; $j < $end; $j++) {
            $start_time = $start->format('Hi');
            $start->modify('+5 minute');
            $end_time = $start->format('Hi');


            $query1 = "INSERT INTO golf_list (golf_name, golf_type,  location, start_date, end_date, start_time, 
                        end_time, currency, price_type, details, gate, status)
                        VALUES ('', 'others', '', '$i', '$end_date', '$start_time', 
                                '$end_time', 'IDR', '$price_type','$details', 'royal', '0')";

            echo "$query1<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much , just different some minute with your answer. I can solve now, and my answer same :D